# Could Luke have killed Yoda?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, luke-skywalker, yoda

From the [script](https://web.archive.org/web/20120205073735/http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/esb-script.shtml) (emphasis added):

> **Nervously**, he looks around at the **foreboding jungle**.
>
> LUKE: Still...there's something familiar about this place. **I feel
>   like...I don't know...**
>
> STRANGE VOICE: Feel like what?
>
> Luke **jumps out of his skin**. Artoo screeches in terror. The
>   young warrior **grabs for his lightsaber** as he spins around,
>   looking for the speaker. **Mysteriously standing right in front
>   of Luke** is a strange, bluish creature, not more than two feet
>   tall. The **wizened little thing is dressed in rags**. It motions
>   toward Luke's sword.
>
> LUKE: (looking at the creature) Like **we're being watched!**
>
> CREATURE: Away with your weapon! I mean you no harm.
>
> After some hesitation, Luke **puts away his weapon**, although
>   he really **doesn't understand why**. Artoo watches with interest.

By the time Yoda reveals himself, Luke is clearly on edge. From the jungle simply being creepy to almost witnessing R2 get eaten by the swamp monster, his survival instincts must have been through the roof. When Yoda spooked him, there was, more than likely, a high chance Luke would have attacked out of sheer reflex.

At this point in the movies, we're not sure of Yoda's health or power, but when he lifts the X-Wing, it requires much more time (and possibly focus) to get it done when compared to his shows of strength from Ep. III, even after Luke warmed it up for him.

**Is there any reference or evidence that states, if Luke had followed through with his attack, that Yoda wouldn't have been able to react in time and've been killed?**

Comment: He could have *tried*.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Probably because the title is a bit click-batey and the question _looks_ like opinion-based (lol, even got a close vote :D). Have my +1 though, I'm interested in what Valorum will post as an answer :D

Comment: @Gallifreyan - How did you know?

Comment: @Adamant `No, try not; do. Or do not, there is no try.` - Yoda

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about a "what-if" scenario which never happened.

Comment: I'd vote to keep it open. It presents a simple question and the answer comes from canon sources.

Comment: @Mooz - Well, then, he would have *done not*.

Comment: To use Sith logic, if Luke could have killed Yoda, Yoda would not be a good teacher (master) for Luke ;)

Comment: Stupid question, but why is this tagged `star-wars-legends` rather than `the-empire-strikes-back`?

Comment: @MrLister 1) Because I always accept Legends answers. 2) Since I was asking more about something meta from that movie, I didn't think it was appropriate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Would he have killed Yoda?

**In a word, No.** Yoda was projecting no threat, or rather projecting an *aura of calm*. Luke evidently has sufficient Force abilities to sense that there's no danger here, even if he was slightly startled. On top of that, Luke for all of his many flaws certainly doesn't seem to suffer from an itchy trigger finger.

The [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_V:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back_(novel)) mentions that Luke senses Yoda's presence but doesn't sense any animosity.

> For the moment, Luke could not decide whether to be frightened or to
>   laugh. But **when he gazed into those bulbous eyes and sensed the
>   being’s kindly nature, he relaxed.** At last the creature motioned
>   toward the pistol in Luke’s hand.

The [original script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html) also seems to imply that Luke has been mind-tricked by Yoda. Again, Luke has sufficient Force power to *realise* that something weird is happening, but insufficient power to prevent it.

> **LUKE:** (looking at the creature) *Like we're being watched!*
>
> **CREATURE:** *Away with your weapon!  I mean you no harm.*
>
> After some hesitation, **Luke puts away his weapon, although he really 
>   doesn't understand why.**  Artoo watches with interest.

---

### Could he have killed Yoda?

As to whether Luke *could have* killed Yoda (had the mood taken him), the answer is no. Yoda has the Force on his side. An untrained Jedi would be no match to Master Yoda's ability to control animals, to use the Force to deflect blaster fire, throw objects, to mind-trick opponents and to outright control them if the need arises.

On top of that is the fact that Yoda has been watching Luke his entire life. He's got a pretty good handle on the fact that he's a benign soul, incapable of ruthless murder.

Comment: "watching Luke his entire life" - I thought he lived on Dagobah?

Comment: @Gallifreyan - he smoked weed and did astral projection a lot.

Comment: Quite a small point but a reflex reaction to being started on an alien world is hardly 'ruthless murder'.

Comment: That last point is the one I was most curious about. He seems so much weaker when compared to when we see him fight Sidious I wasn't sure if he still had what it took to defend himself.